# Maven download a dependency that is not in the pom.xml nore a library dependency

Tags: maven, jhipster

I have a question.

I'm working on a project generated using jhipster. I'm using maven as dependency management system.

I have added bouncycastle for jdk 1.4. 
Now I want to switch to bouncycastle for jdk 1.5. So I changed the version in the pom.xml. But running ./mvnw, download the version for jdk 1.4. So I have removed it from the external libraries and completely removed it from the pom.xml. But running ./mvnw downloaded the version for jdk 1.4. I have even deleted the bouncycastle directory in .m2/repository. Yet I don't think that there are dependencies that need bouncycastle.

Please I need some help.

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` on the project and see if bouncycastle appears somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @JFMeier. This help me see with dependency was linked to bouncycastle. And I upgraded it to new version. Everything is working now. Thanks